# Specify border size in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have [the following fiddle with this content:](https://jsfiddle.net/xvy2epwg/)

```
<div>

  <div style="border-sizing:70px;border-color:#000000">
    Bla bla
  </div>

</div>
```

I would like this to show a black border of the size specified in `border-sizing`. However, that border does not appear.

Any idea what could be the cause?

Comment: Because you're using the wrong CSS attribute? Try border-width

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no `border-sizing` property, you're looking for `border-width`. You also need to specify a `border-style`, which in your case is probably `border-style:solid`.

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xvy2epwg/1/